# setting default value for MVC bootstrap dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Hopefully this is a very simple question.

I would like "United Kingdom" to be the default country on this dropdown, what should I add to to this line?

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Country, "BootstrapHorizontalDropdown", new { list = Model.Countries })
```

Comment: That's a textbox, not a dropdown. Show all relevant code.

Comment: @CodeCaster - maybe you missed the 'bootstrapdropdown' property?

Comment: I bet there's some JavaScript involved, isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Value", "Text", "1"),  new { @class = "BootstrapHorizontalDropdown" });
```

In below which I denoted as Text is about the text that see you in dropdown, and Value is about the value of the text. Example if the Model.Countries contains List if countries and each list have a values of **CountryName** and **CountryCode** means the code should be like below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryName", "CountryCode", "1"),  new { @class = "BootstrapHorizontalDropdown" });
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception that the property with name "United Kingdom" doesn't exist.  In the debugger on the controller I have confirmed that "United Kingdom" is one of the selectlist items.